# Mean value for dimension in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My numpy array (name: data) has following size: `(10L,3L,256L,256L)`.
It has 10 images with each 3 color channels (RGB) and each an image size of 256x256 pixel.

I want to compute the mean pixel value for each color channel of all 10 images. If I use the numpy function `np.mean(data)`, I receive the mean for all pixel values. Using `np.mean(data, axis=1)` returns a numpy array with size `(10L, 256L, 256L)`.

Answer (score 8):

If I understand your question correctly you want an array containing the mean value of each channel for each of the three images. (i.e. an array of shape `(10,3)` ) (Let me know in the comments if this is incorrect and I can edit this answer)

If you are using a version of numpy greater than 1.7 you can pass multiple axes to `np.mean` as a tuple

```
mean_values = data.mean(axis=(2,3))
```

Otherwise you will have to flatten the array first to get it into the correct shape.

```
mean_values = data.reshape((data.shape[0], data.shape[1], data.shape[2]*data.shape[3])).mean(axis=2)
```